# Are Hibernate Pessimistic Locks Distributed with EHCache/Terracotta?

Tags: hibernate, transactions, locking, jta, terracotta

Can Hibernate implement pessimistic locking at the start of a Java transaction, or does it instead rely on a pessimistic lock being applied when all the work in the Java realm is done, and then the changes are applied to the database as part of a database transaction?

I ask as I've got a Java transaction, halfway through which a call to a remote web service is made, which is non-transactional and thus cannot be rolled back. If Hibernate holds a pessimistic lock on the data being acted upon, then the processing of the transaction should be blocked as Hibernate knows another thread is already acting upon those data. If Hibernate *doesn't* keep a track of such locks itself, then the Java transaction will continue, invoking the webservice, and then blocking on the DB commit.

What I really want to happen is for the Java transaction to start, another thread attempt to start another transaction, and block/fail because there's already one in progress for the relevant data.

How is the locking behaviour affected when Hibernate's using EHCache as a 2LC in a distributed fashion with Terracotta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate pessimistic locks are database locks. The locking is delegated to the database. The second-level cache has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It's worth to note that **optimistic** locking is also cluster-safe.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to find out if there is any way of pessimistically locking a JTA transaction in a distributed environment.

Answer (score 0):

"Hibernate does not lock objects in memory."

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html

Nothing like a bit of RTFM :)